# Extracting HTML meta tags in Nutch 2.x and having Solr 4 index it

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

I am using Nutch 2.0 to crawl some websites but I do not see HTML meta tags like title, description are extracted and stored in MySQL database. Any idea how can I get it work?

Thanks
Arash

Comment: The latest Nutch version is 2.1. Also, please check my below answer.

Comment: @how did you run the nutch2.0 I used nutch 2.2 src. when i run it says NoClassDefFound Error :/org/apache/nutch/crawl/crawler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to include the `parse-metatags` and `index-metadata` plugins in your `plugin.includes` definition in `nutch-site.xml`

Then add `metatags.names` `index.parse.md` and `index.content.md` properties and point them to the appropriate tags. Take a look at mine:

```
<property>
        <name>plugin.includes</name>
        <value>protocol-http|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags)|index-(basic|anchor|metadata)|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>metatags.names</name>
        <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>index.parse.md</name>
        <value>metatag.description,metatag.author,metatag.twitter:image</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>index.content.md</name>
        <value>author,description,twitter:image</value>
</property>
```

Test your configuration. I ran this test against an article on readwrite.com:

```
bin/nutch indexchecker http://readwrite.com/2013/03/20/whats-behind-china-attacks-on-apple-and-android
```

The output will tell you if you're parsing the correct values. In my case I wanted `author`, `description` and `twitter:image`:

```
fetching: http://readwrite.com/2013/03/20/whats-behind-china-attacks-on-apple-and-android
parsing: http://readwrite.com/2013/03/20/whats-behind-china-attacks-on-apple-and-android
contentType: text/html
content :   What's Really Behind China's Attacks On Apple And Android? – ReadWrite Sections Sections Social Mobi
title : What's Really Behind China's Attacks On Apple And Android? – ReadWrite
host :  readwrite.com
metatag.author :    Brian S Hall
tstamp :    Wed Mar 20 13:33:38 EDT 2013
metatag.twitter:image : http://readwrite.com/files/styles/150_150sc/public/fields/China%20graphic%20brian%20final.jpg
metatag.description :   Repeated outbursts suggest China could be growing concerned over America's dominance in the smartpho
url :   http://readwrite.com/2013/03/20/whats-behind-china-attacks-on-apple-and-android
```

A downside is that `parse-metatags` will only match tags by name and not property. For example `<meta name="foo" content="bar">` is fine while an Open Graph tags like `<meta property="og:image" content="http://readwrite.com/sample.jpg" />` will be missed.

Comment: I think your explanation works only for 1.x series. Index-metatags is not included in 2.x series yet. Please check http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Plugins

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is one of the reasons I am still on Nutch 1.6 -- unless it is a hard requirement you can't control I would recommend the more stable and feature rich 1.6 version.

Comment: Yes. It is the stable version. I just want to mention it is for 1.x series :) Good explanation. Also, If I am right you can parse the properties of tags with Tika.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [IndexMetaTags](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexMetatags) plugin for Nutch, available from version 1.5 onwards.

This will allow you to specify which meta tags to parse and index.

Note:  The names of the fields must be prefixed with 'metatags.'

You can check the index using [Nutch indexchecker](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20indexchecker)

Comment: Well, I haven't implemented it from scratch, but I've seen it work. We used nutch 1.5.1, if memory serves me right.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan how did run the nutch2.0 I used nutch 2.2 src. when i run it says NoClassDefFound Error :/org/apache/nutch/crawl/crawler

Comment: @jackyesind - sorry, it was a while ago, and I've moved to another project. I'll try to dig up details.

Answer (score 0):

Index-Metatags plugin is not included in the 2.x series. Please check http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Plugins for more information. There is a patch in there that makes the plugin work for 2.x series.

1.6 is the stable version for Nutch right now as the above author has pointed out in the comment.

Comment: Hi how would i run the nutch 2.2.1. It has src only not binary

Comment: To use this patch with 2.2.1, you need to first apply the patch and then run 'ant runtime'. This would create the binaries. You can move to nutch mailing list and ask questions there since the community is very active there

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [latest patches](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1478) regarding Nutch 2.x

Although i can store metadata in the database, i can't figure out how to transfer it to Solr.